# Combobox query in Access 03 database showing on some pc's limited data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a combobox which looks at a table and displays it's 5 columns of data via a query to be used like a search, on most pc's all 5 columns populate with data but on some only the last 3 columns populate and it displays blank FirstName and Surname columns, any idea how this could happen or how to fix it?

Also the combobox isn't used to select just to confirm that searched for people are in the database so there are no events and it is all setup in the combobox properties.

Edit- I bet a post topic like this could stack up those tumbleweed badges if one could get more than 1 of em.

Comment: Guessing nobody remembers too well how to use access 03.

Comment: I remember how to use Access, but this is very odd indeed. What happens if you run a query to extract the same data as the combo?

Comment: it all displays perfectly fine in the query table just in the combo is fails to load Surname and FirstName but has no issue with DOB and 2 other fields which are text types just like F/S name.

Comment: All I can suggest is continuing to test by creating a combo on a blank form that references the same query string. Presumably these guys have the same copy of the front-end as the guys with a working combo? Does everyone have the same version of Access?

Comment: yep everybody is using the same copy in the same network drive and with access03 but some machines just don't want to show the F/S name columns of data.

Comment: I have just noticed that I am also taking to you in another thread :) Is this the same DAP stuff? If it is an Access front-end, people should have their own copy, only the back-end data should be shared.

Comment: Lot's of us still work in A2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be two causes.

One possibility is that the number of rows being returned in a query is not the same as the combo box Column Count property.  If you are changing the combo box Row Source property make sure the updates have the same number of columns.    MS fixed this bug but I'm not sure when it was fixed.

More likely though is that the PCs in question don't have the following hotfix installed.
[Description of the Access 2003 post-Service Pack 3 hotfix package: December 18, 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945674)

Comment: I'd think it to be the hotfix since nothing get changed with the db to get it to work on 1 pc and partially not on another

Comment: Seems my admin permissions don't extend to the laptop I can test it out on so in the mean time I'll be looking for alternatives.

Comment: mananged to install the hotfix and that resolved everything, thx for the help.