# Access Input textbox on Data Access page with only select enabled to allow filter by searchs

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a data access page which gets all it's data from a query of another table, problem is all the textboxs I make on the page and bind the Control source to the matching column then don't allow me to input any text in to use the filter option to search all the results.

I don't want to be able to record any information but if I change page properties to from DataEntry = false too true then it no longer displays the whole section of textboxs.

Anybody know of a way round this or suggestions of other simple solutions to display certain data from the table or all the data from the query in the same/similar way as this?

Edit- [Original issue which now requires me to find new solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680344/combobox-query-in-access-03-database-showing-on-some-pcs-limited-data)

Comment: I know most programmers hate access heck I don't much like it either but I just need a simply way to display and search through all the data located in the access query/table.

Comment: I think the main problem here is Data Access Pages, even people who use Access regularly do not use DAPs. There used to be a DAP fan on tek-tips.com, I do not know if he is still there.

Comment: any other idea then how I could display a access query and use it as a search to look throught the results?

Comment: There are quite a few ways to do this, it all depends on where you want to do it. On someone's desktop? On an internet? Inranet? In Access? In something else?

Comment: btw If you want me to see your comments immediately, you can use @remou, the @ sign is a useful way of posting to someone's StackOverflow inbox.

Comment: @Remou ah ok used it before but didn't know it served any function other than just pointing out who ur talking to on the page, It's only rly 1 tablet machine which needs it fixed on but otherwise for use in access or a local machine would be how I'd want to display this info and allow quick searching through it.

Comment: Oops, I just re-read your post without the blindness caused by DAPs. You should not use bound textboxes for data entry for searches - unbound textboxes are the way to go. It is not too difficult to run up a .hta for searching a recordset if DAPs are not working out.

Comment: well how would I make a DAP then and get the filter to correctly filter the selected column based on whats in each textbox if they are unbound? heading home from work now so won't be checking this again till monday, thx for whatever advice u may give in advance.

Comment: I do not know anything about DAPs and I do not know anyone except that one guy on tek-tips that does, that was the point of my original comment. If you want to do a search of a Jet/ACE recordset in virtually anything else, I can help to varying degrees. If you know DAPs, you may be able to correct the problem you are having with unbound controls, but I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original issue has now been resolved but I had also found these [1](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1367163), [2](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;271728) links which guide one through a search feature on DAP's.

Answer (score 0):

I've used DAP quite a bit -- I even built DAP solutions at Microsoft, and they were wildly popular.  I always preferred to use the SQL Server flavor of DAP.. and that allows you to use *TWO* different types of filters, the standard filter property, in addition to the serverFilter property. The serverFilter property is extremely powerful, and it's incredibly nice to be able to filter things in TWO different ways.

Hope that helps

-Aaron MCITP DBA

Comment: Well I'm going to do a search now into the server filter property but if as it's quite likely that I don't find enough or the right info any chance of a bit more info on how to implement such a filter, bare in mind my end goal is to have a easy search feature for like 5000+ results other than the present DAP of scrolling through the pages till I find something or finding the right 1st/surname and clicking to filter by that, also added in edit a link to a page which details the issue I presently have which has lead me to need a 2nd solution.